# Error al usar un constructor en python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, poo

estaba realizando un trabajo de python 2.7 orientado a objetos, soy bastante nuevo en python, y al ejecutar el código me notifica el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Estoy instanciado el objeto para después serializarlo con el módulo "Pickle" y guardarlo en un fichero como objeto con el fin de poder tratarlo más adelante con el siguiente código:

```
def insertarSolicitud():

    #Esta parte pide por consola los datos al usuario que busca empleo

    nombre = raw_input("Introduce tu nombre:")
    apellidos = raw_input("Introduce tus apellidos: ")
    dni = raw_input("Introduce tu D.N.I: ")
    edad = raw_input("Introduce tu edad: ")
    empleo = raw_input("Que empleo buscas")

    nombreFichero = dni + '.dat'

    #Aqui abrimos el fichero
    fichero = file(nombreFichero, 'w')

    #En esta parte hacemos uso de pickle para serializar el objeto empleado y poder escribirlo como objeto
    empleadoAuxiliar = Empleado(nombre, apellidos, dni, edad, empleo) #Usamos el constructor

    # Usamos el modo de codificacion 1 por que es binario y por lo tanto mas efectivo
    pickle_EmpleadoAuxiliar = dumps(empleadoAuxiliar, 1)
    fichero.load(pickle_EmpleadoAuxiliar)#lo cargamos en el fichero con el metodo load

    fichero.close()
```

El constructor es el siguiente:

```
def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, dni, edad, tipoEmpleo):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.apellidos = apellidos
    self.dni = dni
    self.edad = edad
    self.tipoEmpleo = tipoEmpleo
```

Y los imports que tengo al .py principal son estos:

```
from PracticaSSII import Empleado
from PracticaSSII import Empresario
from pickle import dump, load, dumps, loads
```

PD: si alguien sabe alguna página dónde se explique la OOP de python estaría muy agredecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problemas como indica el propio error se debe a que estas llamando a un módulo (archivo `.py`) no a una clase, método o función contenida en él. Por ejemplo, `Empleado` en tu caso debe ser una clase contenida dentro del módulo llamado `PracticaSSII.py`

Si tu módulo se llama `Empleado.py` e intentas hacer lo que haces te lanza ese error. No se si es tu caso, de no serlo te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y añadas el contenido completo de `PracticaSSII` y la estructura de la carpeta donde están estos archivos a ver si podemos descubrir que está pasando.

Para aclararlo un poco deberias tener la siguiente estructura:

- Dentro de una misma carpeta tener los archivos `PracticaSSII.py` y el módulo donde llamas tienes la función `insertarSolicitud()`, para mi ejemplo lo he llamado `main.py`.
- El contenido de `PracticaSSII.py` debe ser algo así:

  ```
  class Empleado():
      def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, dni, edad, tipoEmpleo):
          self.nombre = nombre
          self.apellidos = apellidos
          self.dni = dni
          self.edad = edad
          self.tipoEmpleo = tipoEmpleo

  class Empresario():
      #Aquí va el contenido de la clase, al desconocerlo uso pass.
      pass
  ```
- El `main.py` (en tu caso no se como lo llamas) tiene la función `insertarSolicitud`, hay algunos cambios ya que empleas mal `pickle` para serializar los datos y que explico ahora después:

  ```
  from PracticaSSII import Empleado
  from PracticaSSII import Empresario
  from pickle import dump, load

   def insertarSolicitud():

      #Esta parte pide por consola los datos al usuario que busca empleo

      nombre = raw_input("Introduce tu nombre:")
      apellidos = raw_input("Introduce tus apellidos: ")
      dni = raw_input("Introduce tu D.N.I: ")
      edad = raw_input("Introduce tu edad: ")
      empleo = raw_input("Que empleo buscas")

      nombreFichero = dni + '.dat'

      #Aqui abrimos el fichero en modo binario
      fichero = file(nombreFichero, 'wb')

      #En esta parte hacemos uso de pickle para serializar el objeto empleado y poder escribirlo como objeto
      empleadoAuxiliar = Empleado(nombre, apellidos, dni, edad, empleo) #Usamos el constructor

      # Usamos el modo de codificacion 1 por que es binario y por lo tanto mas efectivo
      dump(empleadoAuxiliar, fichero, 1)
      fichero.close()

      #Ahora ya tenemos el objeto empleadoAuxiliar guardado en el .dat
      #Si queremos obtener los datos usamos el metodo load de pickle
      #Abrimos el fichero en modo binario, en este caso se uso un dni 11111111A

      fichero = open('11111111A.dat', 'rb')
      datos = load(fichero)#lo cargamos en la variable datos con el metodo load
      fichero.close()

      #Ahora datos es la instancia de la clase Empleado de antes y podemos recuperar los datos (atributos de la clase):
      print 'Recuperando datos de objeto serializado:'
      print datos.nombre
      print datos.apellidos
      print datos.dni
      print datos.edad
      print datos.tipoEmpleo

  insertarSolicitud()
  ```

Puedes ver la [documentación de pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) para más información si lo deseas, el método `dump` de `pickle` permite serializar un objeto python en un archivo, el primer argumento es el objeto en cuestión (en tu caso `EmpleadoAuxiliar`), el segundo el archivo donde lo vas a guardar y el tercero el modo. Si el modo es 1 o mayor debes siempre **abrir los archivos en modo binario**.

El método `pickle.load` no sirve para cargar el objeto en un archivo sino para leer una cadena o archivo de texto y retornar el objeto original, en tu caso permite recuperar los datos del empleado desde el `.dat` retornando el objeto original.

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta podemos correr el programa, te dejo una captura junto a la estructura de la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba, como si me hubieras leido la mente.